# Why doesn't MPI supply serialization interface?

Tags: c++, performance, serialization, mpi, protocol-buffers

MPI is Message Passing Interface, but when you want to send a object you must serialization before MPI_Send.

MPI exposes the communication function to developers and give lots of interface to satisfy it. But why doesn't MPI supply serialization?

I know serialization does not belong to MPI and I wonder there is still something worth to optimize in serialization technology?

Thanks!

Comment: As you already mentioned, serialisation is something you do at a higher level and does not belong in MPI deals mainly with message passing. Furthermore, MPI implementations are essentially C libraries (with C++/Fortran bindings) and as such will have no concept of classes and so serialisation is not application within the MPI standards.

Answer (score 0):

MPI is a platform-independent standard for message passing and the simpler its operations are, the more portable it is. Because of that simplicity most MPI libraries support heterogeneous architectures - you can run your application on a mixed cluster of 16-, 32-, and 64-bit machines that have different internal data representation and even different ABIs.

Serialisation of C++ objects is in no way simple nor portable. You can always use your favourite C++ serialisation library and exchange the blobs it produces using MPI messages. There is even a special type in MPI for sending binary data as is - `MPI_BYTE`.

Besides, support for C++ is being completely removed in the forthcoming MPI standard version 3.0 and C++ programmers are encouraged to use the C functions instead.